# If a business or REIT wanted to purchase Real Estate and keep the owners anonymous could it use Monero to do so?

Tags: privacy, payment-id

As mentioned above, could a REIT (Real Estate Investment Trust) purchase property or send funds to where it needed to go and keep the transaction private between the buyer and seller? What Steps would the business take in setting up its address to hold Monero? I assume downloading Monero's software for a Mac or PC would be the first step after we establish the transaction is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer is more an answer about law rather than Monero.

Part of any real estate transaction is the recording of the transaction in public records.  The parties to the transaction must be known.  The seller must be known, since they must be proven to be the lawful owner of the land.  The buyer must be known, since they must be able to be proven as the lawful owner in the future.  More than likely, the government will impose real estate taxes, so the government needs to know who to tax.

In short, this particular use case doesn't seem like a good one for Monero (generally), since exchanging real estate isn't really a peer-to-peer transaction.

As far as setting up an address, any wallet software will create an address for you.  Be sure to write down the 25-word seed and store it in a safe place, since the seed can be used to restore your wallet and recover your funds in case the wallet file is corrupted/lost/deleted/etc.

Comment: good stuff.  But a 'trust' can ad a layer of obscurity.